# ¿Cómo ordenar de A a Z cada linea de un archivo con Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Necesito ordenar de A a Z cada línea de un archivo de texto con mas de 500.000 palabras. Cada una de éstas en una línea.

**Ejemplo del archivo original:**

```
abad
cabezota
bacanal
...
```

**Ejemplo del archivo que necesito:**

```
aabd
aaabcln
aabceotz
```

Muchas gracias.

Tengo que comentar, que he estado utilizando el siguiente código. Pero solo para unas pocas de líneas y no para 500.000. La compilación deja de responder, consumiendo casi 100 por 100 de los recursos CPU.

**Fragmento de codigo Vb.Net**

```
Public Function Ordenar(ByVal Fuente As String) As String  
    Dim chrs() As Char = Fuente.ToCharArray()  
    Array.Sort(chrs)  
    Return New String(chrs)  
End Function  

Private Sub BtnOrdenar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOrdenar.Click  
    For Each lns As String In RichTextBox1.Lines  
        RichTextBox2.AppendText(Ordenar(lns) + vbCrLf)  
        Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola , por favor agregar el código intentado hasta ahora (un avance) , exponiendo el problema o en que lugar se quedó para así poder darle una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Las opciones faciles que tienes aprovechando que tu archivo ya esta separado por linea cada palabara, haz la lectura del archivo e introduce cada linea como un elmento de una lista o arreglo y usa el metodo ordenar en el arreglo o lista y reescribe los elementos en el archivo de nuevo ya ordenados en la lista o arreglo. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que pones en tu respuesta probablemente te vaya muy lento porque estás haciendo un bucle innecesario para cada fila. No necesitas un bloque `For Each` para usar `Array.Sort`. Tu código deberia ser simplemente:

```
Dim read As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(read)
Array.Sort(readText)
File.WriteAllLines(TextBox2.Text, readText, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Aun así, tratándose de un número tan elevado de registros, es posible que tarde algun tiempo.

**EDIT**

Al parecer entendí mal la pregunta. De lo que se trata es de ordenar los caracteres dentro de cada linea. Para conseguirlo, podemos usar LINQ de una forma sencilla. No puedo probar el rendimiento ya que no tengo un archivo de texto tan grande, espero que sea suficientemente bueno:

```
Dim readText() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\temp\test.txt")
Dim ordenados = readText.Select(Function(x) New String(x.ToArray().OrderBy(Function(y) y).ToArray()))
IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\temp\test.txt", ordenados, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

**Editado rafman.**
Arreglando un poco la codificación, ya lo hemos conseguido.

```
Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
Dim ordenados = readText.Select(Function(x) New String(x.ToArray().OrderBy(Function(y) y).ToArray()))
File.WriteAllLines(TextBox2.Text, ordenados)
```

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @rafman eso es por un problema de codificacion. Añade `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` al método `WriteAllLines` y debería funcionarte. He editado la respuesta para que lo veas

Comment: Me di cuenta cuando ya había hecho yo el comentario de que no podía codificar la salida. Y elimine dicho comentario sin ver que ya habías dejado otro con la solución. He marcado tu respuesta como valida para resolver el problema. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: De nada, me alegra haberte ayudado :)

Comment: `Dim read As String = (TextBox1.Text)
        Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(read,  Encoding.Default)
        Array.Sort(readText)
        File.WriteAllLines(TextBox2.Text, readText)`

Comment: Ahora me he dado cuenta que no ordena los caracteres de cada línea. Que las escribe tal cual. Claro con las prisas al ver que escribe el nuevo archivo tan rápido supuse que todo estaba bien. Pero no es así.

Comment: @rafman Ok, entonces entendí yo mal. No tienes que colocar las lineas en orden, si no dentro de cada linea los caracteres en orden?

Comment: @rafman mira la edición que hice a mi respuesta, a ver si se ajusta a lo que necesitabas

Answer (score 0):

Carga el archivo [Método File.ReadAllLines (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx); ya que tienes el `string[]` vacíalo en un [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) y de este invocas el método [sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx)
finalmente escribes al archivo [Método File.WriteAllLines (String, String())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Con ayuda de sus comentarios y respuesta, he intentado lo siguiente

```
    Dim read As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(read)
    Dim strg As String
    For Each strg In readText
        Dim chrs() As Char = strg.ToCharArray()
        Array.Sort(chrs)
        Dim wrte As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim appendText As String = chrs + Environment.NewLine
        File.AppendAllText(wrte, appendText)
    Next
```

Pero sigue siendo lento para un archivo de 100.000 líneas.